# Create an interactive list in a Wolfram notebook that choosing its items make a change in calculations

Tags: function-construction, dynamic, notebooks, interactive

I have 3 variables. I want to create an interactive list of items in a Wolfram notebook that if I choose each item, functions that are written by myself change the value of the variables and recalculate all the expressions.
For example items are a b c and the variables are a1 a2 a3. If I choose item a, I want item a to become equal to b, etc. Then all related calculations should automatically be updated.
I was wondering if anyone can help me in creating such a functionality.

Comment: Look at the documentation for [`Manipulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html)

Comment: Include the code of what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Quick solution

Create a slider for 'a' between 0.1 and 1; you can change the slider's value as shown in the animation.

```
{Slider[Dynamic[a], {0.1, 1}], Dynamic[a]}
```

[image: slider]

Now create a plot for `Sin[a x]`. The Plot is wrapped inside a Dynamic[ ... ] block so that it refreshes automatically when 'a' changes. Evaluate the cell.

```
Dynamic[
 Plot[Sin[a x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
  PlotTheme -> "Monochrome",
  GridLines -> Automatic,
  PlotRange -> {{0, 2 \[Pi]}, {-1.1, 1.1}}
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

Now you can create three such sliders. Remember whatever you need changed must be wrapped in a Dynamic block.

More advanced functionality is available through Manipulate for which you need to read the docs.